# Changing the default value of a parameter in a function, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array of functions, and I need to change the default value of the parameter with another value for each of them in a loop .. is this possible? Ex:

```js
var externalValidations = [
  function required(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'required field'
  },
  
  function requiredTwo(v, model = {}) {
     console.log(model)
     return v !== null || 'required field'
  },
]

externalValidations.forEach(item => {
  // --> Can I here somehow change the default value of a parameter for each function?! .. so it looks like this:
  // function requiredTwo(v, model = {value: 'value'}) {
  //   console.log(model)

  //   return v !== null || 'Campo obrigatório'
  // },
  console.log(item)
})
```

Comment: envelop function in yet another function?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: How about `[default => function required(v, model = default) { /*...*/ }, /*...*/]`, then `externalValidations.map(it => it({ /*...*/ }))` ...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change what a function does from outside. Also the default initialiser expressions are evaluated on every call when they are needed, they are not static values installed on the function.

All you can do is create new functions that call the old ones, having their own default values and passing them.

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have function f

```
function f(x = 'a') {
}
```

we can change its default value simply enveloping it in yet another function

```
const g = (x = 'b') => f(x);
```

`g` has default argument set to `'b'` when `f` had `'a'`

Comment: was this answer of any help to you?